# ZoomButton in android

Tags: android, zooming

Anybody know the working of zoombutton in android?

I have found some tutorials, but they mention onlyabut .xml file where we can add zoombutton. But I did not get its working in a class.

I want to zoom one image using zoombutton.

Please help me..

Thank you..